# I'm no longer getting prompts for tag names

Tags: bug, status-norepro, tags

When I started on Mi Yodeya, I would ask a question and type in tag names and the machine would prompt me with similar choices that have already been made into tags.  That feature is not working anymore, on this site, or any other Stack Exchange site.  Even if I type in "Kosher" or "Halacha" nothing pops up.  What went wrong?  Note, it works on Meta, however.

Comment: I just tried "kosher" (or, more precisely, "kosh") on main and got several suggested completions.  It wasn't quite instantaneous, though.  How long did you wait?

Comment: Quite awhile.  It's just not working for me anymore.

Comment: Thanks for the info.  Does it happen to you with more than one browser or just one?  Either way, could you edit browser info into the question (browser, version, OS) to help with debugging?  Thanks.

Comment: I'm ok on my blackberry, but not on my home or office PC.

Comment: What browser are you using at home and on your office PC? Also... Try a hard refresh (Ctrl+F5).

Comment: @Shog9:  Tried Ctrl+F5, but no change.

Comment: Is this still happening? Can you please post details of where this is happening? Is this consistently the case everywhere for you? Do you happen to have JavaScript disabled?

Comment: It is still happening on my office computer, but only when I initially ask a question.  If I go back to edit, the prompts appear.  I think we have java script at work -- it would serve our other applications.  Can't tell now; I'm home.

Comment: Can you please give some information about what operating system you are using, what browser and version when this happens?

Answer (score 1):

This problem has been resolved.